# (-1073741571 (0xC00000FD) ) C++ Quick Sort gives error when the size of arrays are larger than 32000

Tags: c++

While I was doing my homework, I got an -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) error which is associated with this code below: My arrays are working perfectly fine when the size is less than 32000. However, after 32000, the program stops executing. I'm using dynamically allocated arrays in the main function. After creating and initializing an array, I call the quickSort function. The problem occurs when arrays are in descending or ascending order.
Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
void quickSort(int *arr, const int size, int &compCount, int &moveCount) {
    compCount = 0;
    moveCount = 0;
    quick_sort( arr, 0, size - 1, compCount, moveCount, 0 );
}

void quick_sort( int* arr, int first, int last, int &compCount, int &moveCount, int pivotIndex) 
    if( first < last ) {
        partition( arr, first, last, pivotIndex, compCount, moveCount );
        quick_sort(arr, first, pivotIndex - 1, compCount, moveCount, first);
        quick_sort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, last, compCount, moveCount, pivotIndex + 1);
    }
}

void partition( int* arr, int first, int last, int& pivotIndex,
               int &compCount, int &moveCount) {

    int pivot = arr[ first ];
    int lastS1 = first;
    int firstUnknown = first + 1;

    for( ; firstUnknown <= last; ++firstUnknown ) {
        compCount++;
        if( arr[firstUnknown] < pivot ) {
            ++lastS1;
            moveCount++;
            swap( arr[firstUnknown], arr[lastS1] );
        }
    }

    swap( arr[first] , arr[lastS1] );
    moveCount++;
    pivotIndex = lastS1;
}
```

Comment: errorcode -1073741571 indicates that Stack Overflow has happened -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

Comment: Can you share your `main` and show how you are initializing your arrays?

Comment: You're always using either first element or last element in the array as pivot. In case of a sorted array you thus always split n elements into subranges of 1 and n-1 producing the worst-case scenario of quicksort (O(n²)).

Comment: I wouldn't pass the pivot as parameter, instead select it from given range by some heuristics. You might e.g. chose a random element or the median of first, middle and last element in the range as proposed by [Sedgewick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot).

Comment: @Aconcagua, In my homework, the instructor said that we are supposed to take
the first element of the array as a pivot. Therefore, I am always using the first element as the pivot. Is there any way to do ascending and descending arrays by selecting the first item as the pivot?

Comment: @hasatserinkan You might be expected to implement the [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) – to achieve better partitioning you might select the pivot as proposed above and then just *move* it to front... Still you don't need the parameter, if always choosing first element it will be identical to `first` anyway.

Comment: @selbie Actually, I'm initializing my arrays in a method and calling the function. My code is ---- void createAscendingArrays(int *&arr1, const int size) {

    arr1 = new int[size];
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if( i == 0 ) {
            arr1[i] = 1;
        }
        else {
            int number = 1 + rand() % 2;
            arr1[i] = number + arr1[i - 1]
        }
    }
}

Comment: You're initialising your array way too complex; As you assure`number > 0` and and add that to the predecessor's value to get the successor you could just initialise any value to `i` – sorted as well, and if comparing `3` and `4` instead of `7` and `9` is totally irrelevant, the actual relation remains the same...

Comment: Note, too, that `rand() % SomeMaximum` produces rather bad distribution; better is `rand() * SomeMaximum / RAND_MAX`, though depending on the values of the two maxima you might have to care for overflow (general advice, doesn't play a role here).

Comment: The way you have been told to do the partition does not work well with ascending or descending arrays. But you've been told to do it so.... Maybe the next lesson will be on how to do it properly

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah sir. I thought that too but giving always the i value to the arr[i] is not making it random. It would be the same array always but the size differs. Therefore, I have done this kind of initialization.

Comment: @john nope, we have already done sorting algorithms :/

Comment: It's not making it random – but if you have a *sorted* array anyway it doesn't matter at all; as there are no random elements in pivot selection every single comparison will give the same result, only the values provided for differ. You could follow and verify if you started a debugger twice, each one with the accordingly initialised arrays ;)

Comment: Have you tried increasing your stack size?

Comment: @Eljay how can I increase my stack size?

Comment: On Unix using Bash, you can use `ulimit -s 52428800` to set the stack size to 50 GB.  On Windows using CL.EXE you can use [set stack size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @Eljay I changed the stack size on Code Blocks and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of `int pivot = arr[ first ];` means that for an ascending or descending array you have a 1:n-1 split. For 32000 elements that means a recursion depth of 32000 and that simply overflows the stack.

The crucial part of quicksort is picking the pivot element and apparently that choice has been taken away from you.

I can think of only one workaround to make it not fail:

After partitioning sort the smaller part first and then sort the larger part. If the compiler doesn't turn that second sort into a tail call then use a goto or loop and turn it into an iteration manually.

The runtime will still be O(n^2) but the recursion depth will be O(log n).

PS: are you allowed to randomly shuffle the input? That makes the ascending/descending case nearly impossible.

Comment: No sir, the main purpose of this homework is to analyze performances of bubble sort, merge sort, and quick sort by sorting different sized arrays (4000 to 40000) with different orders(random, ascending, descending). I haven't got any problem with bubble sort and merge sort or any problem with a randomly ordered array with a size of 40000 for quick sort. However, with ascending and descending ordered arrays, my program doesn't work after 32k elements for quick sort. Also, we are supposed to use the same algorithm that we learned in class. Hence, I think I should not change my function.

Comment: Then just conclude that it fails with stack overflows at a certain size due to how the pivot is chosen. Exercise done.

Comment: @Aconcagua That wouldn't fix the broken not-quicksort implementation, it would just shift the problem around.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Fully agree (*'still not infinite'* was intended as hint to). Might shift the problem to unreasonable large arrays, though – with result of the algorithm appearing to require unreasonably large amounts of *time* then. Hm... Well let's forget about that, crash is a better illustration of the problem, which seems to be the intention of the task anyway ;)

Comment: I changed my stack size and the program works now :D Thanks to all of you guys!